# Stop restart loop in kiosk mode with crashing application

Tags: powershell, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I have a Windows 10 LTSB 2016 machine set up in kiosk mode to run a single application. I followed the Powershell instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher#configure-a-custom-shell-using-powershell to build the install script, it works well. In that script, I can set the behavior of the shell if the application crashes. I can restart the application, restart the PC, or shut down the PC.

In general, this is all good, but occasionally someone does something like edit a file that causes the application to instantly crash on starting. Because I have the script set to restart the application, this causes the shell to get stuck in a loop where the application is rapidly crashing and restarting. This fills my logs and is generally a poor UX for the end user.

I'd like to condition the behavior so the application only attempts to restart a limited number of times, then shuts down (or some other behavior). Is there any way to achieve this? Can the custom shell access a counter, or accept a return statement from the application (e.g. to differentiate between an intended application shutdown/restart vs an application crash)?

Comment: Did you link to the correct docs article? It doesn't contain any mention of install scripts, restart settings or similar.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, no I did not. Link corrected, question updated. The script I used is the one in the link, with only my particulars edited (file location, etc.). I can add my full script to the question, if it would help.